# Efficient scissors congruence between efficiently describable convex polytopes and simplex?

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, computational-geometry, congruences, decomposition-theorem

Is there a convex polytope in $\mathbb R^n$ describable by only $O(poly(\log n))$ half-plane inequalities with positive volume (so at least $n+1$ vertices) such that the standard simplex has a scissors congruence to it and

1. each piece of decomposition has $O(poly(\log n))$ half-plane inequalities to describe
2. we need only $O(poly(\log\log n))$ decompositions?

> At least if we allow each piece of decomposition to have only $O(poly(\log n))$ half-plane inequalities then how many decompositions do we need?

Comment: Doesn't a convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with positive volume need at least $n+1$ half-space inequalities? (I am not sure what a "half-plane" inequality in  $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be.)

Comment: Trivial convex sets are disallowed.